# Variable does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, variables

I'm new to C# .NET. I would like to ask how this works... What I want is just to show an age selection from 1 to 100.

Inside the `.aspx` file I put this code, I used data binding for the variable `listAge`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="AgeDropDown" runat="server">
     <%# listAge %>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here's the code-behind for it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        string listAge;
        listAge = "<asp:ListItem>"+ i +"</asp:ListItem>";
    }
}
```

The error shown inside the `.aspx` is:

> *Error Creating Control: `AgeDropDown` - Code blocks are not supported in this context.*

Because of the variable `listAge`?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the <% %> section in .aspx and in code behind you should do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    AgeDropDown.Items.Clear();   
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        AgeDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(),i.ToString()));
    }
}
```

From another point of view there are several flaws in your code:

1. You are generating ASP.NET tags in code behind. ASP tags are processed on the server and are rendered into html tags. You were practically inserting a  tag in html, which browsers will render as simple text since it's not a valid HTML tag.
2. You were creating a new listAge variable on each iteration of the for loop. Even if the code would work it would display just the last item

Comment: I just edit the code like this `AgeDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));` and it works!

Comment: Btw, what's with the double `i.ToString()` for?

Comment: the second parameter is the value associated with the item, it can be something different like an id or something

Comment: @Eron One of the constructors for ListItem has the following signature ListItem(string text, string value), which create a ListItem like this <asp:ListItem Value="value">Text</LisItem>. This is used in case the text being shown is not the same as the value that you store in the database. E.x. a country dropdown shows country names, but in the database you store country ids (0 in database; United States in dropdownbox).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the server version of `AgeDropDown`.

```
ListItem li;
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
    li = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
    AgeDropDown.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in asp.net or MVC?

Probably

... <%# listAge %>

should be

...  <%= listAge %>